# In Okular, How to Highlight the Selected Text?

Tags: kde, okular

The Highlighter Tool ignores the text selection at the moment of choosing the tool.

I would like to select the text first, then apply the highlighting effect via menu or
shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can reverse the “order of operation,” lacking a better term, and select then highlight text.
However, you can select the “pushpin” on the annotation toolbar to make the highlighter tool persistent:

[image: Screenshot of Okular toolbars]